# Regex for finding dates in a string

Tags: java, regex

Hello people thanks for the help so far. I Have a regex for finding a date in a given string and it does not seem to working. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The code goes something like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d(?:,)$");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text1);

List<String> removable1 = new ArrayList<String>();             
while(match.find()) {
    removable1.add(match.group());
}
```

I know that there is a date "7/2/2013" contained in the string text1 which is not being written to the list removable1. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern does not allow for single-digit days and months. Make the leading `0` optional:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d(?:,)$
```

Also, I'm not sure what the trailing comma does. And additionally, you say "contained in the string", but `^` and `$` anchor the pattern to the start and end. So you might want to remove these, if you want to *find* dates:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d
```

Finally, if you want to make sure that both date separators are the same character, you can do this:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2(19|20)\\d\\d
```

Finally, for some optimization, avoid capturing where you don't need it (and potentially make the century optional:

```
(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d
```

Comment: Hi one simple question. Say the date is surrounded by a couple of strings before and after and I want to match the regex pattern between those particular strings, would this work [^string1 string2 (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2(19|20)\\d\\d string3 string4$]

Comment: @newtoprogramming yes it should (provided those square brackets are not part of your pattern). why don't you just try it?

Comment: this is the exact line for which I am trying to write a regex "commented on 7/2/2013 (version1.0)" for which, I tried "commented on (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d (version 1.0)" and also "(?<=commented\\son\\s(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d?=\\s(version 1.0))" neither detects my pattern. Can you help me. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String text1="07/02/2013";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$");
```

Comment: Are you sure changing the input is a valid solution? ^^ I think this is about matching the given input and not finding an input matched by the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

regex you used is not correct. Task section to match day for example

```
0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

This regex means 0 should be used as prefix if day is 1~9.

To fix this issue , you should add ? which means preceding item is optional. So you can change your regex string to

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

In future, you can use regular expression tester to  debug those issues. They are useful and helps to save time. For example,
http://regex.uttool.com  ,  http://regexpal.com/

Comment: For Java problems, the OP should rather use http://regexplanet.com. I don't know about regex.uttool.com, but regexpal uses JavaScript's regex flavor.

Comment: Both of these two are using javascript regex flavor.